# R markdown bullets in new line

Tags: r, r-markdown

When I output a pdf r markdown file
this:

```
Hypertension was defined as following:
* Previous recorded diagnosis of hypertension
```

gives this:
[image]

and this:

```
Hypertension was defined as following:

* Previous recorded diagnosis of hypertension
```

gives this:
[image]

I the linebrake to happen normally and have the bullet just under the preiovus line.

I was able to do this with

```
Hypertension was defined as following:\
* Previous recorded diagnosis of hypertension
```

but its extremally annoying to do this for every bullet.

Any other options?

Comment: Do you have at least two spaces at the end of each line?

Comment: what's your question?